# Unable to understand the Bubble Sort algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, bubble-sort

```
void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size) {
  int i, j, temp;

  for (i = 0; i < (array_size - 1); ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < array_size - 1 - i; ++j) {
      if (a[j] > a[j+1]) {
        temp = a[j+1];
        a[j+1] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the Bubble sort algorithms why do we start with the 1st element and not the 0th element. As we see there is a (++i) and (++j). 
This is the only but i cant seem to grasp in the code.

Comment: You should indent your code properly, it will help you understand what's going on faster.

Comment: I think Google would explain better .

Comment: Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: `why do we start with the 1st element and not the 0th element.`...are you sure?

Answer (score 3):

The for loop does not behave the way you think it does. The last part, here `++i` and `++j` are executed *after* the loop has been gone through, not *before*. `i++` and `j++` would do exactly the same here.

```
for (
     i = 0; //First part, executed before the first loop
     i < (array_size - 1); //Second part, executed before each loop
     ++i //Last part, executed AFTER each loop
     )
```

Comment: ... but many C programmers "automatically" use pre-increment (`++i`) in this context since it can be faster in other contexts. :) Basically, if you want to increment a variable and don't immediately need the result of the expression, use (or expect others to use) pre-increment.

Answer (score 2):

You are starting with the 0th element. The ++i only your code effects if it is used on the same line, not in a for loop:

- ++i will increment the value of i, and then return the incremented value.

  i = 1;
   j = ++i;
   Now i=2 and j=2
- i++ will increment the value of i, but return the original value that i held before being incremented.

  i = 1;
   j = i++;
   Now i=2 but j=1

Answer (score 0):

```
 void BubbleSort(int a[], int array_size)
{
int i, j, temp;
for (i = 0; i < (array_size ); i++)
{
    for (j = i+1; j < array_size ; j++ )
{
        if (a[i] > a[j])
{
temp = a[j];
a[j] = a[i];
a[i] = temp;
}
}
}
}
```

I  hope above code is comparatively easier to understand.
you can get a better understanding if you follow through the following animation
[bubble sort animation](http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/animation/web/BubbleSort.html)